# JS - Check if value is in-between multidimensional array value's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a value is between 2 (or 4, 6, 8, depending on the selection) other values.

I have an array of prices:

```
[[0, 500], [500, 1000], [1000, 2000], [2000, 10000]]
```

Next I need to check if my array of product prices is somehow in-between one of those values and show the product when it's a hit. but hide other products that aren't in the price-range(s).

```
var checkedItems = [];   
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=price]:checked');
var products = document.getElementsByClassName("products");
```

Then I check what checkboxes (prices) have been checked so we can use it for our filter

```
$(checkboxes).each(function( index ) {
            var box = this;
            checkedItems[index] = [Number(box.dataset.min), Number(box.dataset.max)];
        });
```

To access the products and it's price I simply throw in a foreach

**Note. The price is embedded in a dataset (data-price)**

```
       $(products).each(function( index ) {
            var product = this;
            var price = Number(product.dataset.price);
            //...
        });
```

Now that I have both the prices that have been selected and all the products, how to continue? because when I try to check one value against the array it always returns a false because if a price is between `0 - 500` and I also select `500 - 1000` then it returns false on the latter even if the first one is true. I tried to use `return;` when it hits but that also doesn't seem to do the job.

Simply put; I need to show/hide multiple products based on the price selection.

You guys have any idea?

Comment: Just use a boolean flag ... Initialize with `false`, then loop over your intervals. If you find a match, you set the flag to `true`, and break out of your loop. Check the content of your flag after that loop, to determine whether you want to output the current product or not.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was actually pretty simple as was suggested by CBroe.

Whole code:

```
    var checkedItems = [];
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=price]:checked');
    var products = document.getElementsByClassName("products");

    $(checkboxes).each(function( index ) {
        var box = this;
        checkedItems[index] = [Number(box.dataset.min), Number(box.dataset.max)];
    });

    $(products).each(function( index ) {
        var product = this;
        product.style.display = "block";

        if (checkedItems.length > 0) { product.style.display = "none"; }
    });

    $(checkedItems).each(function( index ) {
        var item = this;
        var min = item[0];
        var max = item[1];

        $(products).each(function( index ) {
            var product = this;
            var price = Number(product.dataset.price);

            if (price >= min && price <= max) {
                product.style.display = "block";
                return;
            }
        });
    });
```